# Is it legal that retail employees are threatened on a near daily basis (UK)?

Tags: united-kingdom

My friend works in a 2nd hand electronics shop where often customers are less than happy at prices or quality of goods they received for whatever reason. These customers often will throw tantrums and act belligerently towards staff - going so far as verbally threatening them almost every other day. The employer seems to be aware of this but isn't doing anything really to help out.

Regardless of how common this is, is it legal for an employer to turn a blind eye to the abuse of its staff like this?

Note: I am a layperson when it comes to law so let me know if this question needs improving.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While this would be uncommon in an electronics store, there are many professions in which it is commonplace for the people they deal with on the job to be verbally belligerent towards them on a regular basis.

For example, police, prison guards, people who tow illegally parked cars, bar bouncers, customer service hotline officials, return desk officials at department stores, airline gate operators, psychiatric ward nurses, parking ticket issuers (i.e. "meter maids"), sheriffs in charge of evictions and repossessions, sports coaches in competitive leagues, bartenders cutting people off, waitresses at certain kinds of restaurants, etc.

It isn't obvious that there are any countermeasures that the employer could take to make things better and the job needs to be done. If there is a real risk of physical violence, the employer probably had a duty to take adequate safety precautions to address that.

Comment: Not my downvote, but there are Commercial Off The Shelf solutions to detect such verbal aggression, which can be used to call in (additional) security. My employer has been selling such software for 15+ years. Your last sentence is the essence: such solutions are required when the verbal aggression carries a risk of escalation to physical violence. This gets you to the standard "reasonable precautions" - which is why it matters that there are off-the-shelf solutions.